# How to create visuals in PowerBI when you have multiple columns with cells with multiple values?

Tags: csv, powerbi

| Names | Region | State | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RFP1 | ERCOT | TX | Storage Only |
| RFP2 | PJM | IN, KY | All Source, Plus Storage, Storage Specified |
| RFP3 | PJM, MISO | IN, LA | All Source |
| RFP4 | SPP | AR, NM, SD | Renewables, Plus Storage, Storage Specified |
| RFP5 | SPP | AR, MO, ND | All Source |

I have an Excel file similar to one above. How do I count each comma-separated value. (i.e. for the above it would be ERCOT = 1, PJM = 2, MISO = 1, AND SPP = 2; and NOT ERCOT = 1, PJM = 1, PJM, MISO = 1, SPP=2)? and have it stay dynamic with the visuals? It is creating calculated columns named Contains ERCOT, Contains PJM etc? or is it something like [this](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/How-do-I-duplicate-rows-based-on-cell-contents-cell-contains/m-p/200606) to duplicate rows?

I've been manually duplicating rows at the source excel file and I want something much less manual.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery, right-click on the `Region` header and select `Split Column` > `By Delimiter...`. In the pop-up:

- `Select or enter delimiter` - select `--Custom--` and enter `,`  (comma space).
- Expand `Advanced options` and select `Split into` `Rows`.

You should now have a row for each `Region`. From here you can create a DAX measure to give you the row count.

Alternatively, if you simply want a count - then in DAX create a Calculated Column with:

```
Region Count = 
  var r = SUBSTITUTE([Region], ", ", "|")
  return PATHLENGTH(r)
```